# Three.js and GLSL: Scaling a Texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl, vertex-shader

I use GLSL for custom transition of two cube textures. Both textures mix into each other with `mix` function. Now I want to have my first texture (`tCube0`) to also slightly zoom (scale) before hiding itself during transition.

See code below. I try to change `scale0` to value `2` with my JS but no visual change occurs: `uniforms['scale0'].value = 2`

```
<script>
uniforms = { mixAlpha: {value: 1}, opacity: {value: 1}, scale0: {value: 1}, scale1: {value: 1}, tCube0: {value: 'CubeTexture'}, tCube1: {value: 'CubeTexture'}, tFlip: {value: -1} }        
</script>
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    uniform samplerCube tCube0;
    uniform samplerCube tCube1;
    uniform float scale0;
    uniform float scale1;
    uniform float tFlip;
    uniform float opacity;
    varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
    #include <common>
    void main() {
        vec3 vWorldPositionScaled0 = vWorldPosition*scale0;
        vec3 vWorldPositionScaled1 = vWorldPosition*scale1;
        vec4 tex0, tex1;
        tex0 = textureCube(tCube0, vec3( tFlip * vWorldPositionScaled0.x, vWorldPositionScaled0.yz ));
        tex1 = textureCube(tCube1, vec3( tFlip * vWorldPositionScaled1.x, vWorldPositionScaled1.yz ));
        gl_FragColor = mix(tex0, tex1, mixAlpha);
    }
</script>
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
    #include <common>
    void main() {
        vWorldPosition = transformDirection( position, modelMatrix );
        #include <begin_vertex>
        #include <project_vertex>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can test out frag/vert shaders on shaderfrog

Answer (score 2):

The texture coordinate of `textureCube` is a 3D direction vector, it does a 3-dimensional look up. Cube map textures are not sampled like 2D textures. The direction goes out of the center of the cube, which is surrounded by its 6 sides. The texel on the side which is hit by the direction vector is returend by `textureCube`. The length of the direction vector does not affect the result.

[image]

See Khronos documentation [Cubemap Texture Access](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Cubemap_Texture)

> The sampler type for cubemaps is `gsamplerCube`. 
>   The texture coordinates for cubemaps are 3D vector directions. These are conceptually directions from the center of the cube to the texel you want to appear. The vectors do not have to be normalized.

This means that scaling the texture coordinate does **not** cause different results.

To achieve a the effect you want you have to change the field of view (the perspective). One possibility would be to add a vector in the direction of the line of sight to the texture coordinate. Note, the line of sight is the view direction, the direction from the camera position to the camera target. Use a scale factor which starts at 0.0 and slightly increased.

```
vec3 texCoord3D = normalize(vWorldPosition) + scale * lineOfSight;
```

or

```
vec3 texCoord3D = mix(vWorldPosition, lineOfSight, scale)
```

Extension to the answer:

After changing the uniforms, you have to set the `needsUpdate` property of the `ShaderMaterial`:

```
uniforms = {
    tCubePosition0: {type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3()},
    tCubePosition1: {type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3()},
    ..... };

materials = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { uniforms: uniforms, ..... } );

.....

uniforms['tCubePosition0'].value = camera.getWorldDirection();
uniforms['tCubePosition1'].value = camera.getWorldDirection();
.....
materials.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: So how can I zoom/scale the texture?

Comment: thanks, how exactly can I calculate the lineOfSight? I already have a camera set up with direction user panned to. I used `new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( FOV, (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight), NEAR, FAR );` to initially set it up and then user can pan it around.

Comment: @Vad The line of sight is the negtive Z axis of the view matrix. You can get tihs vectror with [**`.getWorldDirection ( )`**](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/Camera.getWorldDirection) from the `PerspectiveCamera`

Comment: I tried as `vec3 vWorldPositionScaled0 = vWorldPosition + scale0 * tCubePosition0;` where `uniforms['tCubePosition0'] = camera.getWorldDirection()` AND `scale0` increments from 0 to 0.5 but no scaling occurs.

Comment: No effect still. Maybe I am doing something simple incorrectly: http://appogeddon.com/sample3/.

Comment: The proposed solution does not really address my issue. No scaling is happening.

Comment: Thank you for continuous help on this. Setting `needsUpdate=true` causes JS error: _Cannot read property 'x' of undefined_ Example is updated: http://appogeddon.com/sample3/

Comment: Thanks. If I add `tCubePosition0: {type: "v3", value: null}` to uniforms I get the same _x of undefined_ error. If I do not put that in uniforms but set it during user action, I get the same error then. So either way, error seems unavoidable.

Comment: I updated code as you point out but error stays on scroll up/down. I tried needsUpdate in ShaderMaterial directly with no luck.

Comment: @Vad Please again read my answer carefully. It has to be `uniforms['tCubePosition0'].value = camera.getWorldDirection();` and not `uniforms['tCubePosition0'] = camera.getWorldDirection();`